# Android App crashes on boot, I cannot make sense of logcat errors

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been experimenting with my project which is due in 2 days and now I cannot get it working at all. It simply won't run. I've the logcat here but I have trouble making sense of it. I am not sure what code to include seeing as there's loads and load of code, so rather I'm hoping someone can just advice me from the logcat of where I need to look to fix my errors. I appreciate any help.

```
 05-19 00:46:20.366: D/AbsListView(10772): Get MotionRecognitionManager
05-19 00:46:20.446: D/libEGL(10772): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
05-19 00:46:20.456: D/libEGL(10772): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
05-19 00:46:20.461: D/libEGL(10772): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
05-19 00:46:20.466: D/(10772): Device driver API match
05-19 00:46:20.466: D/(10772): Device driver API version: 10
05-19 00:46:20.466: D/(10772): User space API version: 10 
05-19 00:46:20.466: D/(10772): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
05-19 00:46:20.506: D/OpenGLRenderer(10772): Enabling debug mode 0
05-19 00:46:20.506: D/AndroidRuntime(10772): Shutting down VM
05-19 00:46:20.506: W/dalvikvm(10772): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4143f2a0)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class comment
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at com.example.DrinkDealzApplication.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter.getView(NavDrawerListAdapter.java:49)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1614)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.comment
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-19 00:46:20.526: E/AndroidRuntime(10772):    ... 44 more
05-19 00:46:20.541: D/dalvikvm(10772): GC_CONCURRENT freed 208K, 6% free 12404K/13191K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 17ms
05-19 00:46:20.541: D/dalvikvm(10772): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
```

I see there's a fatal exception main there so actually here's the main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

There seems to be an error in MainActivity too.

```
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.DrinkDealsApplication.model.NavDrawerItem;
import com.example.DrinkDealzApplication.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PlacesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

If there's anything else you want me to upload just let me know. I am really stuck here so hope someone can help.

edit: Manifest added and I have fixed the MainActivity import problem but it's still crashing on boot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.slidingmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.DrinkDealzApplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyC7WDlHZ6OMODyug3PZRZeCSAladGJUnvE" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: You're using `R.java` from `info.androidhive.slidingmenu` package. If it's not the package of your source (say, you just copy/paste a chunk of code from `info.androidhive` site), remove it.

Comment: manifest has been added! The R.java is being imported from there. Basically I downloaded a fairly basic app from Androidhive and modified it heavily.

Comment: If you fix something, and you still crash, you need to go back to LogCat and see if your stack trace changed. Most likely it did, and you now need to fix your next bug. Continue this process until it works.

Comment: @user2849976 : Post your layout XML files

Answer (score 0):

It's class not found exception, and somehow the files are not bundled or packaged. 
Go to your project properties (right click  and then properties)  then go to the Build path then under import/export, check every thing and hit OK. 
Do a clean and then build again